# Django REST: 'Request' object has no attribute 'field_name'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a post request to add a job application to the list of applicants. This is done by `POST /task-worker/<task_id>`

However, I get the error:

> 'Request' object has no attribute 'task'

**Models.py**

```
class Task_worker(models.Model):
    worker = models.ForeignKey(Worker)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('worker', 'task')

class Task(models.Model):
    ...

class Worker(models.Model):
    ...
```

**serializers.py**

```
class TaskWorkerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    task = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='task.id')
    worker = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='worker.id')

    class Meta:
        model = Task_worker
        fields = ('id', 'task', 'worker', 'created', )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['task_id'] = self.context['request'].task
        return super(TaskWorkerSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

**views.py**

```
class TaskWorker(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = TaskWorkerSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        task_id = self.kwargs.get('task_id', '')
        queryset = Task_worker.objects.filter(task__user=self.request.user, task_id=task_id).distinct()
        return queryset

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        worker = Worker.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        task = Task.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('task_id', ''))
        serializer.save(task=task, worker=worker)
        #ALSO TRIED
        #serializer.save(task_id=self.kwargs.get('task_id', ''), worker=worker)
```

Even if I don't have `task` explicitly in `perform_create()`, I still get the same error, saying request has no task attribute.

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^task-worker/(?P<task_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.TaskWorker.as_view()),
```

---

EDIT: Full Traceback.

```
Traceback:  

File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/godo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py" in __getattr__
  410.             return getattr(self._request, attr)


      During handling of the above exception ('WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'task'), another exception occurred:



File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/godo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/godo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/godo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/godo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/godo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/godo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  494.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/godo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  454.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/godo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  491.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/godo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py" in post
  244.         return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/godo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in create
  21.         self.perform_create(serializer)

File "/Users/gr/Desktop/PycharmProjects/godo/api/views.py" in perform_create
  42.         serializer.save(task_id=self.kwargs.get('task_id', ''), worker=worker)

File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/godo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in save
  214.             self.instance = self.create(validated_data)

File "/Users/gr/Desktop/PycharmProjects/godo/api/serializers.py" in create
  25.         validated_data['task_id'] = self.context['request'].task

File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda/envs/godo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py" in __getattr__
  412.             return self.__getattribute__(attr)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /api/task-worker/17/
Exception Value: 'Request' object has no attribute 'task'
```

Comment: you want to add entry to Task_worker model ?

Comment: @VikasDamodar Yes, but because it's a many-to-many (Task_worker) is a trough table, I needed to specify task_id

Comment: It's not clear were that error is happening. Please post the full traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Added

Comment: I think problem in serializers.py, Can you add that one also ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need this line `validated_data['task_id'] = self.context['request'].task` in serializer's create method. Task wil be added automatically.

Also you dont need `validated_data['worker'] = self.context['request'].worker` if you have this.

From the docs:

> Any additional keyword arguments will be included in the validated_data argument when .create() or .update() are called.